# SwiftData relationship fault not occuring when fetching the model

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

This may or may not be a bug or my misimplementation.
When two objects have a relationship with each other one is usually faulted until it is being used in order to preserve space in the memory.
This is the default behavior in CoreData.

However, I am getting my hands dirty with SwiftData and i am seeting that no relationship fault occurring. All the data is being fetched which will be difficult for the memory to handle and i was wondering if my implementation is wrong.

I have two models a Person and a Possession

the Person model has a one to many relationship to the Possession model.

meaning each possession can only have one person but a person can have multiple possessions.

I have set my model like the following

```swift
@Model
class Person {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    let personID: String

    @Relationship(.cascade, inverse: \Possession.person)
    var possetions: [Possession]?

    init(id: String, possessions: [Possession]) {
        self.personID = id
        self.possetions = possessions
    }
}
```

possession:

```swift
@Model
class Possession {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    let id: String

    let name: String?

    var person: Person?

    init(id: String, name: String, person: Person) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.person = person
    }
}
```

If i set a breakpoint i see that all the posessions are loaded into the memory this is something i do not want to happen.

In Core Data we get a relationship fault however, i am not seeing the same behavior in SwiftData.

here's how my view is implemented

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @EnvironmentObject private var navigationStore: NavigationStore
    @Query() private var people: [Person]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(people) { person in
                NavigationLink(value: person) {
                    VStack {
                        Text(person.personID)
                    }
                }
                .swipeActions {
                    Button("Delete") {
                        modelContext.delete(person)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar(content: {
            Button("Add") {
                let newPErson = Person(id: UUID().uuidString, possessions: [])
                modelContext.insert(newPErson)
                do {
                    try modelContext.save()
                } catch {
                    assertionFailure("\(error)")
                }
            }
        })
        .navigationDestination(for: Person.self) { person in
            Text("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

at the launch i do not want possessions to be loaded into the memory. I want them loaded when they are being used.

Comment: I haven’t looked at this closely or tried to reproduce it it feels like this is another example that SwiftData is still in the beginning of its beta cycle, hopefully we will see some real improvements soon. This is a little similar to the fetch limit not working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699005/how-to-limit-the-number-of-items-in-a-fetch-request